# Automatic generation of code for redirecting methods to an object when implementing an interface in Java

Tags: java

I want to override a method of ResultSet interface in jdbc. I could not extend the class (DelegatingResultSet) that implements in ResultSet interface. There are a lot of methods in ResultSet interface and overriding them one by one and calling the corresponding method from the ResultSet object is time consuming. Is there any easy way for generating methods of interface filled with calling the same method of a ResultSet object?

Let me give an example:

```
public class MyResultSetImplementation implements ResultSet {
    ResultSet rs;


    public MyResultSetImplementation(ResultSet rs) {
        super();
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rs.unwrap(iface);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rs.isWrapperFor(iface);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rs.next();
    }
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: You can use a proxy approach, but it will use reflection. [One example is here](https://opencredo.com/dynamic-proxies-java-part-2/)

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can right click on the rs property -> Source -> Generate Delegate Methods. If you dont want to write code at all you can use Proxies (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

Comment: Thank you Meini and KevinO. I already implemented proxy approach but because of performance issues I want to redirect method calls. Source->Generate Delegate Methods is fine for me.

Comment: Usually such things are made using creating a proxy implementing only methods of interest, and dispatching other invocations to delegate object by reflection. This may be made e.g. using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`